# Problema ao exibir rotas em Api Root

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Tenho um arquivo urls.py no projeto com rotas da minha API, estou importando as rotas e concatenando em uma variável chamada api_urls, para depois fazer um include da variável com as rotas, mas ao fazer isso, somente as rotas de router_usuario aparecem na página API Root, porque, pela ordem foram as primeiras que eu adicionei em api_urls. Como eu faço para listar todas as rotas na página API Root?

**URLs do Projeto**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

from usuarios.urls import router_usuario
from avisos.urls import router_avisos
from boletos.urls import router_boletos
from condominio.urls import router_condominio
from endereco.urls import router_endereco
from registros.urls import router_registros
from reservas.urls import router_reservas
from taxas.urls import router_taxas

api_urls = router_usuario.urls + router_avisos.urls + 
router_boletos.urls + router_condominio.urls \
+ router_endereco.urls + router_registros.urls + router_reservas.urls 
+ router_taxas.urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('', include(api_urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está certo quando diz que somente as primeira urls do seu `+` aparecem no site. Isso porque você está usando o `DefaultRouter` em todas as apps e depois fazendo o import e a nova lista a partir do `.urls`.

Seguindo a linha de utilizar o `DefaultRouter`, a maneira correta de se fazer o "merge" entre eles é:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("rota-1", Rota1ViewSet)

router2 = routers.DefaultRouter()
router2.register("rota-2", Rota2ViewSet)


router3 = routers.DefaultRouter()
router3.registry.extend(router.registry)
router3.registry.extend(router2.registry)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router3.urls)),
    ...
]
```

No seu caso, seria alguma coisa assim:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

from usuarios.urls import router_usuario
from avisos.urls import router_avisos
from boletos.urls import router_boletos
from condominio.urls import router_condominio
from endereco.urls import router_endereco
from registros.urls import router_registros
from reservas.urls import router_reservas
from taxas.urls import router_taxas
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.registry.extend(router_usuario.registry)
router.registry.extend(router_avisos.registry)
router.registry.extend(router_boletos.registry)
router.registry.extend(router_condominio.registry)
router.registry.extend(router_endereco.registry)
router.registry.extend(router_registros.registry)
router.registry.extend(router_reservas.registry)
router.registry.extend(router_taxas.registry)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Se eu não esqueci nenhum import ou algo do gênero deve funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

Cria uma lista, adiciona as urls à essa lista e após isso você terá todas a urls

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

from usuarios.urls import router_usuario
from avisos.urls import router_avisos
from boletos.urls import router_boletos
from condominio.urls import router_condominio
from endereco.urls import router_endereco
from registros.urls import router_registros
from reservas.urls import router_reservas
from taxas.urls import router_taxas

lista_urls = [router_usuario.urls, router_avisos.urls, 
router_boletos.urls, router_condominio.urls,
router_endereco.urls, router_registros.urls, router_reservas.urls, router_taxas.urls]

api_urls = [row for row in lista_urls]


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('', include(api_urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Comment: Infelizmente, não funcionou. Ocorreu um erro, segue o stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/XwEPbvfL

Comment: pastebin é bloqueado pra eu ver aqui, se puder colocar em outro local: dontpad

Comment: aí está: http://dontpad.com/XwEPbvfL

Comment: Como que estavam vindo as urls do jeito que estava antes? Da um print no api_urls e manda pra mim no mesmo site por favor

Comment: Essas são as urls que eu tô importando para o urls.py do projeto: http://dontpad.com/urls

Comment: Antes, as urls estavam sendo adicionadas assim: http://dontpad.com/api_urls, conforme é mostrado na pergunta, entretanto, apenas a 1ª url que eu adiciono em api_urls é mostrada em Api Root